# Webdriver selenium - can't find any element from TradingView

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to using Selenium but I watched enough videos and followed enough articles to know something is missing.  I'm trying to get values from TradingView but the problem I'm running into is that I simply can't find any of the elements, not by Xpath or Css.  I went ahead and tried to do a simple visibility element test as shown in the code below and to my surprise it times out.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
# Stops the UI interface (chrome browser) from popping up
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='c:\se\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/")

timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]")))
    print("Page loaded")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
driver.quit()
```

I tried to click on one of the chart buttons too using the following and that doesn't work either.  I noticed that unlike many other websites for Tradingview the elements don't have names and don't generate a relative path (only full) using Xpath.

```
driver.find.element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]').click()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show a screenshot of what you want on the page? or the html code

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be an issue with xpath.
When I try to click the AAPL button it is working for me.
The xpath I used is:

```
(//div[contains(text(),'AAPL')])[1]
```

If you specify exactly which element to be clicked I will try.
And also be familiar with the concept of frames because these type of websites has lot of frames in it.